# Получить только путь

Tags: php

Есть строка `<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">`

как средствами php вырезать только путь src что бы получилось

```
images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)** с передачей массива вырезаемых элементов спокойно может подойти:

```
$inputString = '<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">';

$cuttingData = array('<img src="', '">');
$result = str_replace($cuttingData, '', $inputString);

echo $result;
```

---

с использованием **[Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)**:

```
$html = str_get_html('<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find("img") as $element) {
    echo $element->src , "<br>"; // выведет images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg
}
```

посмотреть можно на http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jkmb-miie

```
$html = str_get_html('<div><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg"><img src="images/stories/2015/10/2-52.jpg"><img src="images/stories/2016/12/2-53.jpg"></div>');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find("img") as $element) {
    echo $element->src , "<br>";
}

// Выведет 
images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg
images/stories/2015/10/2-52.jpg
images/stories/2016/12/2-53.jpg
```

посмотреть можно на http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iws5-2vex

---

C помощью **[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)** (уже есть нативно в *PHP*)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src').'<br/>';
}
```

-

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg"><img src="images/stories/2015/10/2-52.jpg"><img src="images/stories/2016/12/2-53.jpg"></div>');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src').'<br/>';
}

// Выведет 
images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg
images/stories/2015/10/2-52.jpg
images/stories/2016/12/2-53.jpg
```

Comment: Спокойно подойдет, если не будет ничего лишнего. `$inputString = '<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" alt="WTF?">';` Пусть чуть  больше кода, но я бы предпочел класс `DOMDocument`

Comment: @Deonis я тоже в первую очередь подумал про dom parser. Но я без понятия о всех входных данных ТС - откуда строка, как точно выглядит и зачем. Поэтому на данный конкретный вопрос - такой ответ  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Deonis но добавил пример с DOMDocument  и Simple HTML DOM Parser, чтоб был. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант так:

```
$html = '<img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">';
$src = preg_replace('/.*<img[^>]+src="([^"]+)".*/', '$1', $html);
echo $src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Или с помощью **preg_match_all()**

```
$str = '<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-51.jpg"> текст <img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg">';
preg_match_all('~(?<=src=").+?(?=")~', $str, $a);

var_dump($a[0]);
```