# Помощь c выражением preg_match в PHP

Tags: php

```
<div class="content">
  ....
      <div class="inner">
        ....
      </div>
</div>
```

Как с помощью preg_match взять исключительно `<div class="content">**</div>**` то есть div именно класса content?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765361/191482  смотри последний вариант в ответе

Comment: Не понял ничего.(

Comment: используй [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php),  Люк

Comment: а без него никак? с простым, удобным preg_match данная задача получается частично, то есть парсится </div> из <div class="inner"> а нужно чтобы с content

Comment: на эту тему есть самый популярный и цитируемый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6104996

Comment: @Webmaster можно сначала выбрать всё из <div class="content">, а потом удалить html-теги. Такой результат вам нужен?

Comment: Вот мне что нужно, например <div class="content"></div> вот отсюда нужно взять все что внутри до </div> именно content'a. Это например чтобы если внутри content есть еще другие дивы, то они игнорировались.

Comment: @Webmaster [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1be696fc29b1937a7d19a0249251e9ca0270d0a7)

Comment: В вашем примере все окей, то что нужно, но если $str = preg_replace('~<div[^>]*>.+</div>~s', '', $a[1]); где $str менять на $a не работает, а мне нужно чтобы было $a = иначе скрипт не пашет.

Comment: @Webmaster я ничего не понял из вашего последнего комментария ))